# How to make a solid and hollow square in c based on user input of rows and colums

Tags: c

I am doing an assignment that is suppose to display both a solid and hollow box based on the input of the user and I have run into an error, I need to keep it between 1 and 20. So if the user was to input a number smaller or greater than the range the program should terminate. The error I run into is when the user enters a number greater than 9 the boxes I made won't display. 
please help I need to turn this in by tonight. I extremely appreciate it.

the code can be found in the link [here](https://ideone.com/pvI0mY)

```
#include <stdio.h>

 int main ( void )
 { /* Start of function main */

 int entry; /* initialize number entered by user */

 entry <=20;     /* largest number user can enter */
 entry >=1;       /* smallest number user can enter */

printf( "Enter a number between 1 and 20. " ); 
                      /*obtain a number from   the user */
scanf( "%d", &entry);

if ( entry <= 0 ) { /*if user enters a number smaller than 1 */
   printf( " \n");
   return 0;
}
else if ( entry >= 20 ) { /* if user enters a number larger than 20 */
   printf( " \n");
   return 0;
}
else if ( entry == 1 ) {
   printf( "*\n" );
}
else if (entry == 2 ) {
   printf( "**\n" );
   printf( "**\n" );
}
else if (entry == 3 ) {
   printf ( "***  ***\n" );
   printf ( "***  * *\n" );
   printf ( "***  ***\n" );
}
else if (entry == 4 ) {
   printf ( "****  ****\n" );
   printf ( "****  *  *\n" );
   printf ( "****  *  *\n" );
   printf ( "****  ****\n" );
}
```

Comment: the link has the complete code I created

Answer (score 0):

1- I think the below lines in your code are redundant :

```
 entry <=20;     /* largest number user can enter */
 entry >=1;       /* smallest number user can enter */
```

Did you wanted to comment them? If so, use `//` in the beginning of the line.

2- As I can't open the link that you putted in the question, I can't say what is the problem. But I strongly recommend you to use `for` loop instead of these nested `if` expressions.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ( void )
{ 
int entry=100;
int i,j;

    while (entry>20 || entry<0)
    {
        printf("Please enter a valid number between 0 and 20 :");
        scanf("%d",&entry);
    }

    if(entry==1)
        printf("*");
    else if (entry==2)
        printf("**\n**");
    else
    {
        for(i=1;i<=entry;i++)
            printf("*");

        printf(" ");

        for(i=1;i<=entry;i++)
            printf("*");

        printf("\n");

        for(i=1;i<=entry-2;i++)
        {
            for(j=1;j<=entry;j++)
                printf ("*");

            printf(" ");
            printf("*");

            for(j=1;j<=entry-2;j++)
                printf(" ");

            printf("*");
            printf("\n");
        }


        for(i=1;i<=entry;i++)
            printf("*");

        printf(" ");

        for(i=1;i<=entry;i++)
            printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a C/C++ compiler installed on my computer. I hope it work! :)

Comment: Thank you for the response I put in the code and complied it, but when I ran the code it displayed an empty space instead of displaying a solid square next to a hollow square. Do you have any suggestions on what may be occurring for it to display the empty space instead of the squares?

Comment: @thatguy Please try again. As I was written `int entry=1;` in the first lines, the while loop didn't run. I replace it with `int entry=100;` and it is OK now.

Comment: what line is it that you are referring to?

Comment: @thatguy In the previous version instead of `int entry=100;` I was wrote `int entry=1;`. and a 1 is not less than 0 or greater that 20, the `while` condition was equal to `False` and it never run. So entry was equal to 1 always, and you saw the single star just for that.